# Running angular partial in a new tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am presenting my issue in a simple manner as below

There is a index.html as below

```
Index.html
<script src="js/libs/jquery/jquery.js"></script> <!--JQuery library--> 
<script src="js/libs/angularjs/angular.js"></script>
<script src="js/libs/angularjs/app.js"></script>


{{title}}<br>

<ng-include src="'document.html'"></ng-include><br>
<a href="document.html" target="_blank">newPage</a>
```

My app.js is as follows

```
angular.module('myApp',[])

.controller('myController',function($scope){
    //array to store the items
    $scope.title = "This is a test message";
    $scope.secondPage = "this is the second page"
});
```

The document.html is as follows

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
{{secondPage}}
</div>
```

I need to run the document.html in a new page, but obviously since the document.html does not have the import script of angular.js,app.js it won't render. But if i do put the script statements in document.html there will be multiple imports in the index.html. How do i solve this issue ? 
Require.js would not solve this issue.
One bad way to solve the issue would be import the document.html as text and remove the importing statements.(bad bad way !!)

Comment: why you don't think of any modal popup?

Comment: @pankajparkar yea that would solve the issue but, it blocks the Ui in the background

Comment: but closing modal shows your page.no need of redirect.which make sense

Comment: @pankajparkar i actually need for a webapp where there is a viewer , so functionally the person can open the viewer in a new tab/window and do something else in the the webapp looking at the viewer

Comment: Not clear at all what your issue is or why you need another window in the first place. You can use postMessage API though to communicate between windows

Comment: @charlietfl as told in the previous comment, i have a small image viewer in a webapp which has a button to open the viewer in a new window (this feature is so that the user can open the document in a new full sized window also navigate to other views in the webapp). My viewer partial does not contain the import of jQuery,angular,etc .. so the partial does not render in the new window. Hope i made it clear , let me know if further explanation required. thanks

Comment: as mentioned can use postMessage API to communicate between windows ... pass the rendered html as message data. Seems to me to be easier for user to create viewer in same page

Answer (score 0):

Create a new page for the new window opener similar to index.html

So your code will be like:

Index.html

```
<script src="js/libs/jquery/jquery.js"></script> <!--JQuery library--> 
<script src="js/libs/angularjs/angular.js"></script>
<script src="js/libs/angularjs/app.js"></script>

{{title}}<br>

<ng-include src="'document.html'"></ng-include><br>
<a href="documentwindow.html" target="_blank">newPage</a>
```

documentwindow.html

```
<script src="js/libs/jquery/jquery.js"></script> <!--JQuery library--> 
<script src="js/libs/angularjs/angular.js"></script>
<script src="js/libs/angularjs/app.js"></script>

{{title}}<br>

<ng-include src="'document.html'"></ng-include><br>
```

Hope this works for you

Comment: Hmm interesting , let me give it a try and come back